# Alternate Background color by row in a Grid in the presence of SpanFromAbove

Tags: style, grid-layouts

I have some rows I want to put into a `Grid`:

```
rows = {{a, "foo"}, {b, "bar"}, {c, SpanFromAbove}, 
  {d, "baz"}, {e, SpanFromAbove}, {f, SpanFromAbove}, 
  {g, "quux"}};
```

In order to make it easier to read, I want to use alternating background colors, which I tried to do the standard way:

```
Grid[rows, Alignment -> {{Automatic, Left}, Center}, 
 Background -> {Automatic, {{LightYellow, LightBlue}}}]
```

However, what I get is this ugly mess:

[image: an ugly mess]

What I want looks like this:

[image: a less ugly mess]

In order to get that, though, I had to resort to a rather convoluted solution that explicitly inserts `Item`s around elements to color them.

```
Module[{except = Except[SpanFromAbove], 
  colors = {LightYellow, LightBlue}, split, item}, 

 split = SequenceCases[rows, 
    seq:{{_, except}, {_, SpanFromAbove}...} :> 
     Map[Replace[x:except :> item[x]], seq, {2}]]; 

 Grid[Catenate[MapThread[
     #1 /. item[x_] :> Item[x, Background -> #2] & , 
     {split, PadRight[{}, Length[split], colors]}]], 
   Alignment -> {{Automatic, Left}, Center}]]
```

I could probably make this a bit less complicated with some elbow grease, but it would be really nice if I could somehow tell grid to have the colors alternate based on the spanned groups of rows and let it do the hard work.

Is there a way to do that?

Failing that, is there a really slick way to get the `Item`s where I want them to go?

Answer (score 4):

```
colors = {LightYellow, LightBlue};

rowclrs = Module[{col = colors}, 
   Last[col = If[# === SpanFromAbove, Identity, RotateLeft]@col] & /@ rows[[All, 2]]];

Grid[rows, Alignment -> {{Automatic, Left}, Center}, Background -> {Automatic,{rowclrs}}]
```

[image]

A lengthier alternative:

```
lengths = Length /@ Split[rows[[All, 2]], #2 === SpanFromAbove &];

rowclrs = Flatten @ 
   MapIndexed[ConstantArray[colors[[Mod[#2[[1]], Length @ colors, 1]]], #] &, lengths]

Grid[rows, Alignment -> {{Automatic, Left}, Center}, Background -> {Automatic, {rowclrs}}]
```

[image]

With both methods we can cycle through a longer list of colors. For example, with `colors = {LightYellow, LightBlue, LightRed}` we get

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
rows = {{a, "foo"}, {b, "bar"}, {c, SpanFromAbove}, {d, "baz"},
        {e, SpanFromAbove}, {f, SpanFromAbove}, {g, "quux"}};

rowclrs =
  Module[{i = -1},
    i *= If[# === SpanFromAbove, 1, -1] & /@ rows[[All, 2]] //
      {LightYellow, LightBlue}[[#]] &
  ];

Grid[rows, Alignment -> {{Automatic, Left}, Center}, 
 Background -> {Automatic, {rowclrs}}]
```

[image]